# How to create grouped barplot from hv.Dataset?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I would like to create a grouped bar plot from a pandas.DataFrame using Holoviews Datasets.

In particular I would like to have bars grouped by their original column.
Right now bars are being plotted on top of each other:

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(10,15)),
                   'B' : list(reversed(range(20,25)))})
ds = hv.Dataset(df, kdims='index')
ds.to.bars(vdims='A')*ds.to.bars(vdims='B').opts(alpha=.5)
```

This results in:
[current snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvaE3.png)

However I would like to have them side-by-side, similar to the plot featured in the [official docs](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Bars.html#bokeh-gallery-bars) (bottom of the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For plotting directly with pandas DataFrames I would recommend the [hvPlot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/) library which is built on top of HoloViews. HoloViews deals well with so called  [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html), while hvPlot is built to deal well with both tidy and wide data. Using hvPlot generating the plot you want is as simple as:

```
import hvplot.pandas
df.hvplot.bar()
```

[image: bar plot]

Using HoloViews directly you would have to use `pd.melt` to convert the data into a so called tidy format. That would look like this:

```
hv.Bars(pd.melt(df.reset_index(), ['index']), ['index', 'variable'], 'value')
```

[image: melt_example]

For a neat explanation for what `pd.melt` is doing see [this visualization](http://jalammar.github.io/visualizing-pandas-pivoting-and-reshaping/)

Comment: I wasn't aware of `melt`. With your answer I was able to figure it out. Tyvm!